# Why does numpy indexing work differently in higher dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large array and need to change some of its values, but get inconsistent results depending on the number of dimensions. A minimal example looks like this:

```
a=np.zeros((3,3))
indx=np.array([2,4,6])
a[np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3))] = 1
```

works as expected. However, the following doesn't:

```
b=np.zeros((1,3,3))
indx=np.array([2,4,6])
b[0,np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3))] = 1
```

and gives an array filled with 1.

Questions: Why are these not the same? And how can I mimick the behavior of the first example when I have in fact a higher dimensional array like in the second example?

Comment: What does `np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3))` look like?  And with `(1,3,3)` or `(2,3,3)`?

Comment: With (3,3): (array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0])). With (1,3,3): (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0])). With (2,3,3): (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0])).
So (1,3,3) and (2,3,3) give the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `unravel_index` produce?

```
In [126]: indx=np.array([2,4,6])    
In [128]: i=np.unravel_index(indx,(3,3))    
In [129]: i
Out[129]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0]))
```

A tuple of 2 indexing arrays.  Apply that to 2d array, and we see it sets the reverse diagonal.

```
In [130]: a=np.zeros((3,3),int)

In [131]: a[i]=1

In [132]: a
Out[132]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

How could we set the reverse diagonal on the 2nd plane of a 3d array?  We need 3 indexes, right?

```
In [133]: a=np.zeros((2,3,3),int)

In [134]: a[1,[0,1,2],[2,1,0]]=1
#  a[(1,[0,1,2],[2,1,0])]=1  is the same thing

In [135]: a
Out[135]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]])
```

So now the question is - how to go from `(array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0]))` to `(1,[0,1,2],[2,1,0])`?

For the 1st plane, `(1,3,3)` works because it produces a 3 element tuple.  `(2,3,3)` does the same thing.

```
In [140]: np.unravel_index(indx,(1,3,3))
Out[140]: (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0]))
```

How about concatenating 2 tuples?

```
In [142]: (1,)+np.unravel_index(indx,(3,3))
Out[142]: (1, array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0]))
```

There are number of `numpy` functions that construct indexes by mixing and matching tuples, lists and arrays.

You could also build the tuple from a list:

```
In [153]: ind=[1,0,0]
In [154]: ind[1:]=np.unravel_index(indx,(3,3))
In [155]: a[tuple(ind)]=2
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
b[np.unravel_index(indx, (1,3,3))] = 1
```

Comment: ok, that helps, but I think only if the first dimensions of b is 1 like in the example. What about if it is b=np.zeros((2,3,3)) and I want to do b[1,np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3))] = 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

`unravel_index(indx, (3,3))` returns a tuple of length 2, because `len((3,3))==2`.
If you want to use that tuple to index a 3-dim array with your own 1st dim index, you need to prepend your index to the tuple, to make it a tuple of `length==3`:

```
b[ ([0,0,0],) + np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3)) ] = 1
b
=> array([[[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Now, if the first dim is longer than 1, you can change `[0,0,0]` to whatever you'd like.

---

One more way to understand the problem:

Say:

```
k = np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3))
```

Then you want:

```
b[0,k[0],k[1]] = 1
```

Which is not the same as what you're attempting:

```
b[0,k] = 1
```

---

BTW, a simplified version also works. The first element of the tuple doesn't have to be an array:

```
j = (0,) + np.unravel_index(indx, (3,3))
j
=> (0, array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 1, 0]))
b[j] = 1
```